# ServiceNow Rest API Call Using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

How is it possible to perform the below query with 'user B' while being logged in as 'user A' and not exiting 'user A' session?

```
     var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "www.url.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic [BASE64]",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
        }
```

While being logged with user A, I perform this query and get immediately logged in with user B and my session is overwritten with user B. I'm attempting this while using a Chrome Extension.

The 'User B' account is a generic account with permissions to perform API calls which 'User A' does not have.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible
if (User A has admin role) or (User A has impersonator role && user B is not an admin)

1) If User A has admin role, then they can directly trigger any REST queries as long the target table is allowed to access.

2) If User A has impersonator role, then you can impersonate any users session except the admin users. The following line of script can be used to impersonate user B within user A's session and then trigger the required API as User B

```js
var originalUserID = gs.getUserID();

//Replace SYS_ID_USER_B with the sys_id of user B from the profile
gs.getSession().impersonate('SYS_ID_USER_B'); 

//Trigger REST API as USER B -- START


//Trigger REST API as USER B -- END

//Impersonate back to the original user
gs.getSession().impersonate(originalUserID);
```